# How to convert jpg or png images to dicom format in Lazarus?

Tags: freepascal, lazarus, dicom

The question is clear, How to convert jpg or png images to dicom format in Lazarus?

Comment: Which graphic library are you using? Why do you not specify compiler? Do you really use Delphi?

Comment: i use Lazarus IDE v1.4RC2. I would later use opengl. i load a jpg or png to  image control and now i want convert this image to dicom format, dicom tags does not matter.

Comment: i can write a matlab exe code to convert jpg to dicom, but i need to implement in Lazarus IDE

Answer (score 0):

There are several commercial libraies which support DICOM file format. Or you can build your own.
Basically DICOM is a container. Images withing this containers can have a lot of different formats, including simple RGB raw image (that is 3 bytes per pixel, one for each primary color). The container also contains metadata. This can mostly be fixed. The only exception is image size.
There are plenty of DICOM resources on the web. Google is your friend.

Comment: its crystal clear that Google is our friend. my idea is Google is our enemy, of course, my question is how to convert jpg image to dicom format by Lazarus??